# mongo query is not working properly on linux server PHP mongo linux

Tags: php, linux, mongodb

I have a mongo query which works nice on my local machine on windows

but on the server, which uses linux the same query is not working

By is not working I mean that it executes correctly but is not able to find the data that corresponds to this criteria.

```
MDB::alloc()->{COLL_wall}->remove(
        array(
            '_id'   => new MongoId($wid),
            '$or'   => array(
                array(wall_owner    => $this->id),
                array(wall_writter  => $this->id)
            ),
            wall_owner  => $wallOwner
        ),
        array(
            'safe'  => true
        )
    );
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: Would help if you described what exactly you expect of this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the problem is that your machine on linux the version of mongo is much older and for this reason "or" statement is not working there

Check both your versions and upgrade if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems: a) `new MongoId($wid)` is a bit strange, it's rare to see MongoID getting an argument. $wid is 24 hex chars, right? As MongoID silently ignores everything else and creates a new id, this can be a problem.

Second, are your data types OK? Most grievances with Mongo queries come from the fact that the integer 1 does not match the stored string '1'.

Comment: new MongoId($wid) creates a mongoId from a string for matching
data type is ok, I have checked it. The problem is in '$or' statement.

on windows it finds the element and deletes it, but on linux it fails to do so